# Is there a replay cache in Kerberos version 4?

Tags: networking, kerberos, network-protocols

Does Kerberos version 4 support replay cache like in V5 - a cache that prevents replay attacks which occur within the clock skew, so the TGS knows a duplicate packet has arrived ?

Is it present in version 4 or only 5 ?

Comment: I believe that is new in v5.  Let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Replay cache is new in Kerberos version 5.  See [Kerberos: The Definitive Guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=dGMd-uay-lkC&pg=PT124&lpg=PT124&dq=Kerberos%20replay%20cache&source=bl&ots=JvghqS7486&sig=ACfU3U30oa6CHgtP7ZZzz1ylYZQH7LvqnA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQqPHPxeLhAhUFb60KHQ7HDH8Q6AEwGnoECDEQAQ#v=onepage&q=Kerberos%20replay%20cache&f=false) by O'Reilly Books, page 108.  My link should take you to the exact page:

> Kerberos v5 introduces the replay cache to avoid attackers reusing
>   tickets in the short time period that authenticators are valid.